# Is Google Cloud Messaging an MVP feature?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, startup

I am working at a "startup" and I am developing an Android application. I was wondering if using the Google Cloud Messaging Platform for push notification is an MVP feature.

My thinking is this: In the early stages of a Startup, everything is an assumption. Your idea, your product etc, EVERYTHING. So, is it worth to invest time implementing this feature ( push notification with GCM ) ?

I think the question is going back to whether I really need this feature and if it's a main one. Having push notifications, makes your engagement better etc. The short answer is No, someone could use my app without push notification, but it would be better if it had.

PS: As funny as it sounds, being able to select the few feature that you are going to launch with, it's harder than I was expecting.

Comment: The `mvp` tag seems to have to be removed from the question.

Comment: Too smart as hell, tell me would you like Facebook, Gmail WhatsApp without notification? Then change your short answer to YES

Comment: If the feature is part of the MVP then maybe its down to the implementation. Using a 3rd party provider, like Parse.com, makes integrating GCM really easy and later on when the product evolves you might want to move to your own GCM integration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin Ok, you are right, I think i got my answer, but I don't the tags were off topic. Or if it were, what tags I should have used ? Thanks

Comment: @AlexSpyr Please, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) what questions are on-topic for SO and which ones you should [avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You question is loosely related to software development and totally subjective. It says something like: "Do you think random Android application should have push notifications in the MVP stage?". And as Punit said "it is totally depend on your requirements". What I want to say is that answers to such questions is not going to help neither you, nor future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mvp is Minimum viable product

**Definition** - What does Minimum Viable Product (MVP) mean?

```
A minimum viable product (MVP) is a development technique in which a new  
product or website is developed with sufficient features to satisfy early adopters.
The final, complete set of features is only designed and developed after considering feedback
from the product's initial users.
```

so what you want to add is totally depend on your requirement which you want to provide to initial user.